# Exposing two endpoints with stateless service fabric and asp.net cor

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-service-fabric

I add a stateless service to my service fabric app . I need this service to expose two endpoints : A - endpoint for http listening , B - endpoint for RPC calls
Now I need to use the Startup class that configure the asp.net cor with the dependency injection and all the staff. 
WebHostBuilder already has a method user , but if I use the B endpoint listener (CreateServiceRemotingListener) how I can use the Startup class.

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, can you post some code of what you've tried and how it failed?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Startup class in CreateServiceRemotingListener as it has nothing to do with RPC listener. It was developed to be used for creation of the host for asp.net core apps.